# Is there a way to change selected option with help of function in React?

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I have custom `radio` buttons and `select` with few `options`. By default only some of the options is displayed in select box. When i check any `radio` button then `select` options is changing to some other options. When i uncheck `radio` button then they are changing back to default `select` options. So far everything is fine. But if option is selected and then `radio` button is checked or unchecked again it will change `select` options like it usually does but it will not display first option or default value(which is first option). It will display second or third depends which one was chosen before. Its not jumping back to "Actions"

[image]

```
{!this.state.isAnySelected ?
  <>
    <select defaultValue="Actions">
      <option>Actions</option>
      <option>Category request</option>
      <option>Add new review</option>
    </select>
  </>
  :
  <>
    <select defaultValue="Actions">
      <option>Actions</option>
      <option>Add new product</option>
      <option>View product</option>
    </select>
  </>
}
```

I tried to change defaultValue every time when radio button is clicked but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use controlled form elements in react. you need to keep track of `value` prop, pass it instead of `defaultValue` to make it work.

Solution here

[image: Edit 3vj6vymqjp]

Comment: Will accept yours because question was is there a function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to add a `key` to the two select elements:

```
{!this.state.isAnySelected ?
  <>
    <select key="categorySelect" defaultValue="Actions">
      <option>Actions</option>
      <option>Category request</option>
      <option>Add new review</option>
    </select>
  </>
  :
  <>
    <select key="productSelect" defaultValue="Actions">
      <option>Actions</option>
      <option>Add new product</option>
      <option>View product</option>
    </select>
  </>
}
```

The effect of this will be to re-mount the `select` whenever `this.state.isAnySelected` changes.

Currently when `this.state.isAnySelected` changes, React will just be updating the option text of the existing options, so the currently selected index is unaffected. The "defaultValue" is only going to affect what is selected when the element is first mounted. The two different keys cause React to treat these as separate DOM elements rather than as changes to existing DOM elements, so whenever `this.state.isAnySelected` changes, the previous `select` will be unmounted and the other mounted with the correct default.

Comment: Make sense, i like your answer. Thanks a lot.